# square pos card payment form integration in ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, square, square-connect

I am new to square payment form integration. i am integrating the form according to the documentation on https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/adding-payment-form .when i am embedding the form on a individual page it works fine but when i am loading the form scripts in ajax it showing the error " ReferenceError: SqPaymentForm is not defined ". some one please suggest me a way to embed the form in ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are likely trying to run the javascript on the page (that has something like `var paymentForm = new SqPaymentForm({...` before the external library has loaded.

If you are loading the `https://js.squareup.com/v2/paymentform` asynchronously, you'll need to delay the execution of the javascript on the page until after the external library has loaded. You can do this via onload events, or waiting until the page is fully loaded (or lots of other ways, search for "delaying javascript after async", but the easiest way would be to just load the library synchronously.

Comment: i tried this 
`function loadJavaScriptSync(filePath){
 var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
 req.open("GET", filePath, false); // 'false': synchronous.
 req.send(null);
 var headElement = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
 var newScriptElement = document.createElement("script");
 newScriptElement.type = "text/javascript";
 newScriptElement.text = req.responseText;
 headElement.appendChild(newScriptElement);
}     
loadJavaScriptSync("https://js.squareup.com/v2/paymentform");`  
then called `var paymentForm = new SqPaymentForm` 
now the in console a network error.

Comment: got this too **Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user’s experience. For more help http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org**

Comment: What you are doing isn't really synchronous. Just include `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.squareup.com/v2/paymentform"></script>
` in the `head` of your page